# Which event should be used on text box to call javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having two text boxes to store two dates. I want to call a javascript function upon entering date into the first and second textbox. That is as soonas I enter the date in second box I want to call the javascript function. I tried onchange but it is not calling the javascript function. Can you suggest me the right event to call the javascript function? Thanks in advance. I'm using smarty. My code is as follows:

```
<label>Created Date From</label>
            <div class="form-element">
              <input type="text" class="cal fl-left" name="from_date" id="frmDate" value="{if $data.from_date}{$data.from_date}{else}{/if}" maxlength="10" />
            </div>
<label>Created Date To</label>
              <div class="form-element">
                <input type="text" class="cal fl-left" name="to_date" id="toDate" value="{if $to_date}{$to_date}{else}{/if}" maxlength="10" onchange="get_tests_by_date(); return false;"/>
              </div>
```

Javascript code is as follows:

```
function get_tests_by_date() {
    document.location.href = "view_tests.php?test_category_id="+document.getElementById('test_category_id').value+"&test_mode="+document.getElementById('test_mode').value+"&test_type="+document.getElementById('test_type').value+"&package_type="+document.getElementById('package_type').value+"&created_date_from="+document.getElementById('frmDate').value+"&created_date_to="+document.getElementById('toDate').value+"&page=1";
  }
```

Comment: You could do an on keypress and check if the the box contains the number of characters you allow for the date. Make sure you ignore the backspace key.

Comment: `onchange` should work. Can you post the non-working code, and tell us which browser(s) you've tried?

Comment: @JoAreBy: On your request I've added the code.

Comment: I don't see any reason why `get_tests_by_date()` wouldn't be called. Have you tried replacing that functions body with an `alert("test");`? `onchange` triggers for every keypress that changes the content of the textbox. Reloading for each new keypress might not be what you want. You can add a check to see if the date is complete before the reload.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i ended up doing years ago, no jquery in this code:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="FormStartDate" value="" maxlength="10" onkeydown="KeyDateNumCheck()"/>
<input name="FormEndDate" value="" maxlength="10" onkeydown="KeyDateNumCheck()"/>
```

**JS:**

```
//do not allow to input anything except the numeric characters, dashes, or slashes
function KeyDateNumCheck()
{
  var iKeyCode = event.keyCode;
  if ( (iKeyCode != 109) && (iKeyCode != 189) && (iKeyCode != 111) && (iKeyCode != 191) &&
    ( ((iKeyCode > 57)&&(iKeyCode < 96)) || (iKeyCode > 105) || (iKeyCode == 32)) )
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: why not just use jquery , isnt it easier?

Comment: As long as jquery is not mentioned in the tags, one should answer questions in terms of native javascript.

Comment: @Hello-World It very much is! But as Jo Are By said - it was not in tags, thus author was looking for pure jscript...